# The AccessibleSelection in a AccessibleJMenu is returning after the mouse changes JMenu

Tags: java, swing, jmenu

The code, at the bottom of the question, provides a solution for a fairly specific circumstance where I need to click on a `JMenu` and it should act like a `JButton` whilst keeping almost all of the formatting of a `JMenu`. The difference in formatting between the `ActionMenu` and the `JMenu` should be after it is clicked, it should return to its normal state (see image).

[image]

With the current code it does do this. However; if you are to move your mouse over a different menu or if you move you mouse down/up off the menu and then hover back over it, the menu will go into its selected state (see image). This should not occur.

[image]

My question is why is this occurring after the `AccessibleSelection` has been cleared and the `PopupMenu` has been set to not visible?

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3206847208968227199L;

    private Main() {
        setSize(600, 600);
        setJMenuBar(new MenuBar());
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    private class MenuBar extends JMenuBar {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2055260049565317972L;

        MenuBar() {
            add(new ActionMenu("Menu"));
            add(new JMenu("Another Menu"));
        }
    }

    private class ActionMenu extends JMenu {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -6885806048559452542L;

        public ActionMenu(String name) {
            setText(name);
            menuItem();
        }

        JButton butInvis;

        private void menuItem() {
            butInvis = new JButton();
            butInvis.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
            addMouseListener(new MenuMouseListener());
        }

        private class MenuMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                clcikComponent(butInvis);
            }

            private void clcikComponent(JButton comp) {
                comp.doClick();
            }
        }

        private class MenuActionListener implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {
                AccessibleJMenu aJ = (AccessibleJMenu) getAccessibleContext();
                aJ.clearAccessibleSelection();
                getPopupMenu().setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**
I forgot to mention that orginally I was doing this with `setSelected(false)` on the `JMenu` (see code below); however, that causes the exact same issue when you hover over another `JMenu`.

```
private class MenuActionListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        setSelected(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson Is there something wrong with my approach?

Comment: See [Principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)..

Comment: @AndrewThompson So you are saying not to do this as it will cause confusion with the user?

Comment: Yes.. A button should look and act like a button. A menu should look and act like a menu. When programmers think they know better what components should like like and how they behave, it adversely affects the end user's experience.

Comment: @Dan there are two direct listeners, just for JMenu/JMenuItem and one derived listener (implemented as notifier in API), everything depends of your real requirement or ...:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem you need to use the `AccessibleContext` of the `JMenuBar` and not the `JMenu`. This can be done with the line of code

```
getParent().getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleSelection().clearAccessibleSelection();
```

In this example the code would go in the `MenuActionListener` and it would look like the following code.

```
private class MenuActionListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        getParent().getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleSelection().clearAccessibleSelection();
    }
}
```

---

As mentioned by [Andrew Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418556/andrew-thompson), this should not be done because of the [Principle of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), unless you are going to change the formatting of the component (`Action Menu` in this example) so that it does not look like another component.